# Unable to write in the logs directory - symfony 5

Tags: php, windows, symfony

**The problem**
In all my Symfony projects, since 1 week I can't create controllers, show in localhost what is already done...
In my console it always show the error message  " Unable to write in the "logs" directory (C:\wamp64\www\project/var/log).  "

**My Environment**
Windows 10 Pro
VS Code
PHP 8.2.0
Symfony
wampp
mySql

**Steps I've Taken**
When I check the requirement, Symfony show me the problem below :

```
`Your system is not ready to run Symfony projects 


Fix the following mandatory requirements
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

 * var/cache/ directory must be writable
   > Change the permissions of "var/cache/" directory so that the web
   > server can write into it.

 * var/log/ directory must be writable
   > Change the permissions of "var/log/" directory so that the web
   > server can write into it.`
```

Before this week, everything was ok.
How can I change it ?`

**What I've Tried**

- allow permissions by right clic on the folder but everybody has permissions
- on the folders var/cache and var/ log I can't uncheck the box only reading, it doesn't save it
  In the terminal
- sudo chmod 777 app/logs/ doesn't work
- sudo chmod 777 app/cache/ doesn't work
- umask(0000) doesn't work

I'm new in developpment, and especialy with Symfony and lost by this error. I don't know what I have done to get this error, because it has worked well for 1 week before that...

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have issues with `var/cache` and `var/log`

But you tried to add permissions to `app/logs/` and `app/cache`

Try `sudo chmod 777 var/cache`

Comment: sudo chmod 777 var/cache doesn't work :  The term "sudo" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path exists, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 : 1

sudo chmod 777 var/cache